# How to preprocess test data after one hot encoding

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am a bit confused here, I have one hot encoded my categorical columns for all those < 10 unique values `low_cardinality_cols` , and dropped the remaining categorical columns for both Training and validation data.

Now I aim to apply my model to new data in a `test.csv` that. What would be the best method for pre-processing the test data to match train/validation format?

My concerns are:
1. Test_data.csv will certainly have different cardinality for those columns
2. If I one hot encode test data using low cardinality columns from training I get `Input contains NaN` but my train, valid & test columns are all the same number.

Sample one hot encoding below, this is for kaggle competition/intermediate course [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-data-for-ml-course)

```
# Apply one-hot encoder to each column with categorical data
OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[low_cardinality_cols]))
OH_cols_valid = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.transform(X_valid[low_cardinality_cols]))

# One-hot encoding removed index; put it back
OH_cols_train.index = X_train.index
OH_cols_valid.index = X_valid.index

# Remove categorical columns (will replace with one-hot encoding)
# This also saves us the hassle of dropping columns 

num_X_train = X_train.drop(object_cols, axis=1)
num_X_valid = X_valid.drop(object_cols, axis=1)

# Add one-hot encoded columns to numerical features
OH_X_train = pd.concat([num_X_train, OH_cols_train], axis=1)
OH_X_valid = pd.concat([num_X_valid, OH_cols_valid], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise 2 things:

- `OneHotEncoder` is a parameter `handle_unknown="error"` per default. It should be turned to `handle_unknow="ignore"` in the case that you mention (categories in testing not known during training).
- Use a scikit-learn pipeline including your predictor instead of calling `fit_transform` and `transform` and then give the data to the predictor

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could think, there are two possible solutions to this, I will illustrate both here and you can pick whichever works for you.

**Solution 1**

If it is possible for you to get all the possible levels/values of the categorical variable that you are planning to encode, you can pass them as the `categories` parameter when you perform [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) the default value for `categories` is `auto` which determines the categories automatically from the training data and will not account for the new categories found in testing data. Enforcing `categories` as a list of all possible categories will help us solve this problem. As even if your testing data has new categories that were not present in training/validation data they will all be encoded correctly and you won't be getting `NaN`s.

**Solution 2**

In case if you are not able to collect all possible categories of a categorical column you can go ahead and fit the one-hot encoder the way you have done, and when you try to transform your test data in order to handle `NaN`s which you will be encountering when you find a new class, you can use some kind of imputation techniques like [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn-impute-simpleimputer) or [IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html#sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer) to impute the missing values and process further.

Comment: Solution 1 is a workaround (you are leaking some information from testing during training, thought). Solution 2 should not be used. Imputation does not make any sense here.